# Invoking Controller method from Html page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have created a Html page say `SomePage.Html` and I want that Whenever I visit this page a method should be called.

Suppose I created a Controller `DefautController` and It has method named - `Get()` then whenever I visited the "../SomePage.Html" then this "Get()" should be raised.

SomePage.Html :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function codeAddress() {

            alert('ok');
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="codeAddress();">

</body>
</html>
```

DefaultController :-

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    // GET: Default
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
    }
}
```

How can I do that. I am very naive to this - WebApi/Asp.net thing. thanks :)

Comment: you should use either `PageMethods` or `Ajax Get/Post` call  using this you can call the code behind methods from your `html` page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Default/index',
        data: { },
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
                 alert(result);

        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Method is not getting called :( When I load the page

Answer (score 0):

You have to give method name `Get` instead of `index` method in URL

```
 $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("Get", "Default")',
                            data: {},
                            type: 'GET',
                            datatype: "json",
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            async: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(data.results);
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: I want to run this ajax call - whenever my page loads..how can I do that ?

Comment: Suppose you are using a button to load html page on that button click you will have to call this ajax method.

Comment: <button name="submit" id="somepage"></button> on this button $('#somepage').click(function () {  //write ajax code here });

Comment: I can't use the button.

Comment: Whatever you are using to visit that page make a ajax call for that.

Comment: I updated my question - SomePage.Html -  i am getting alert everytime i am visiting the page. So Now- how can I call the Get Method Of Default Controller - I tried to put the ajax inside that method but not successful.